# Duvida sobre orientação a objetos em Python

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Eu é um colega de sala estávamos fazendo um script eu escrevi meu script
desta forma:

```
detalhes = programa.duracao if hasattr(programa, 'duracao') else programa.temporada
```

No meu caso, eu estou chamando dessa forma! O meu amigo desta forma abaixo, fiquei com duvida quanto ao jeito de escrever e não chegamos a conclusão da melhor for de se fazer a mesma coisa!

```
detalhes = programa.get_duracao() if hasattr(programa, '_duracao') else programa.get_temporada()
```

A pergunta é, qual a diferença entre usar o "_" e quando não usar? Isso não quebraria o conceito do encapsulamento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@weltonvaz o caractere "_" foi utilizado devido a convenção de código do python proposto pela pep8 (documentação da PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ ). De forma mais básica a pep8 propõe como boa pratica de desenvolvimento e legibilidade na escrita de código em python a criação de métodos e variáveis utilizando o formato Snake Case, onde as palavras são separadas pelo carácter _. Por exemplo, criar uma variável chamada "retornar todos valores", ficaria: retornar_todos_valores. O método seria retornar_todos_valores().

Existem outros estilos de escrita como o Camel Case, onde as palavras são escritas todas juntas, mas a primeira letra de cada palavra é escrita em maiúsculo. Esse estilo é muito utilizado no java, onde utilizando o mesmo exemplo citado a cima a escrita ficaria: retornarTodosValores().

No caso do código do seu amigo ele criou o método get para retornar o valor do atributo duracao da classe programa. É comum na programação Orientada a Objetos a criação dos métodos getters (get) e setters (set) dos atributos de uma classe, nesse caso para acessar os valores dos atributos utiliza-se os métodos get que retornam o valor do atributo e para setar valores aos atributos utiliza-se os métodos set que normalmente recebem um parâmetro que são atribuídos ao atributo da classe, por exemplo:

**get_duracao():** retorna o valor do atributo duracao da sua classe programa.

**set_duracao(1):** adiciona o valor 1 ao atributo duracao da classe programa.

No código citado acontece que você está acessando o atributo duracao da classe pessoa diretamente (programa.duracao) e seu amigo utilizou um método para retornar o valor, por isso o código programa.get_duracao(), se você olhar a classe dele é provável que esteja parecido com isso:

```
class programa:

    duracao = 0

    def get_duracao():
        return duracao
```

Recomendo a leitura dos conceitos da orientação a objetos para melhor entender esses conceitos que citei. A Caelum possui uma apostila gratuita de Java que explica bem os conceitos de orientação a objetos, porém, na linguagem java https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/. Mas também existe muito conteúdo de orientação a objetos em python.